# How to prohibit function calls with a certain subtype of a parameter type?

Tags: generics, compiler-errors, kotlin

Suppose I have a generic function:

```
fun <T: Foo> bar(t: T) { ... }
```

Then, later at some point in time, I decided that it is meaningless (or even erroneous) to call `bar(...)` with `T` specialized as `Qux`, which is, of course, one of the `Foo`'s subtypes. But I have a strong reason not to change the classes hierarchy (e.g. I don't have access to that code).

Is there a way to prohibit the calls to `bar(t)` with `T` specialized as `Qux`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to prohibit the calls for a certain generic type argument: the deprecation. Using the [`@Deprecated`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecated/) annotation in this case looks quite clumsy, but it solves the problem (*).

You can define an overload of `bar(...)` with a more concrete type and deprecate the overload with level [`DeprecationLevel.ERROR`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecation-level/index.html):

```
@Deprecated("bar should not be called with Qux", level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
fun <T : Qux> bar(t: T) = bar(t as Foo)
```

After that, when a `bar(...)` call is resolved for a `Qux` argument, the deprecated overload will take precedence because it features more concrete types. Therefore the calls will produce a compile-time error:

```
bar(Qux())
^ Using 'bar(T): Unit' is an error. bar should not be called with Qux
```

<sup>(*) Note, however, that **this will only work for `Qux` as static type** (the one used for the call resolution), and the function can still be called as `bar(Qux() as Foo)`. Quite expectedly, you cannot produce a compile-time error if the argument type is only known at runtime.</sup>

---

The same approach can be used to produce errors or warnings for functions that should only react on `null`s in some way, so that calling them with a not-null type makes no sense:

```
fun checkNotNull(x: Any?) = x ?: throw IllegalStateException("Should not be null")

@Deprecated("It is meaningless with a not-null argument.", DeprecationLevel.WARNING)
@JvmName("checkNotNull--notNullArgument")
fun checkNotNull(x: Any) = checkNotNull(x as Any?)
```